# Uing Vue.JS v-bind:class with conditional statement of dynamically created array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, conditional-statements, two-way-binding

I have a table that is created when an array called `shelves` is created in my Vue app.

```
<table>
  <tr v-for="(shelf, index) in shelves">
    <td>
      <input type="number" v-model="shelf.maxWeight">
     </td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

I want to bind an html class called `error` to each input box created, based on the length of the value in the input box. I was thinking it would be something like this:

```
    <td>
      <input type="number" v-model="shelf.maxWeight" v-bind:class="error: shelf.maxWeight.length < 1">
    </td>
```

But whenever I try to do this, the page does not load and I get an error in the console saying:

```
invalid expression: Unexpected token : in
error: shelf.maxWeight.length < 1
Raw expression: v-bind:class="error: shelf.maxWeight.length < 1"
```

I've been looking [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) but can't seem to find any reference on how to specifically do this.

How do I change the class in my input field based on the length of a value in the array that my table is referencing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`v-bind:class` takes an object as a parameter, as described in the link you provided.

Your code should read

```
    <td>
      <input type="number" v-model="shelf.maxWeight" v-bind:class="{error: shelf.maxWeight.length < 1}">
    </td>
```

Note the curly braces surrounding the class object

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind an object to `class`:

```
v-bind:class="{ error: shelf.maxWeight.length < 1 }"
              ^                                   ^
```